# Webpack Watch callback

Tags: webpack

How can I add the webpack watch callback in my configurations file:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{ loader: "style-loader" }, { loader: "css-loader" }, { loader: "sass-loader" }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(pdf|jpg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "url-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.[hash].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ],
    watch:true,
};
```

In the documentation I found this:

```
const watching = compiler.watch({
    /* watchOptions */
  }, (err, stats) => {
    // Print watch/build result here...
    console.log(stats.hash);
  });
```

but I can't understand how add it, thanks

Comment: you can't, unless you start the webpack process manually via node api

Comment: There is a way to do it in other way?

Comment: No! If you want to control it use the node api.